# Using middleware to check for users session react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

I've spent about 1 week reading up on redux before plunging into anything sizeable. After completing most of the tutorials I've done I realised, ok I understand redux but how the hell do I make a complex system :P

I started going about by creating my systems actions:

```
function requestLogin(creds) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
        isFetching: true,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        creds
    }
}

function receiveLogin(user) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        id_token: user.id_token
    }
}

function loginError(message) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
        isFetching: false,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        message
    }
}
```

But how can I with each router used (using `react-router`) check to see if the user has a session after storing the users logged in state in the redux state?

I wanted to create something that gets executed with each view. Just simply write a function that `exec()`'s in each view?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you create a function that executes whenever you go to a route that requires a login.

```
import LoginActions from '../loginActions';

const requireLogin = (nextState, replace) => {
  store.dispatch(LoginActions.CheckLogin());
  const {login} = store.getState();
  if (!login.isAuthenticated)
    replace('/login');
};
```

Call it in your router:

```
<Router component={Root}>
 <Route path="/dashboard" onEnter={requireLogin} component={dashboard}/>
</Router>
```

Comment: Nice one mate :) I find it weird though, because `CheckLogin` action is literally going to be one line right? `type:LOGIN_CHECK` for example which fires off the reducer right?

Comment: Yeah. You can also chuck your login token into a cookie/localstorage for persistence through page refreshes and check for the token in the CheckLogin() action.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement auth filter for paths requiring the user to be authenticated using Higher Order Components.

Create wrapping component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
export default function(ComposedComponent) {
    class AuthFilter extends React.Component {
        // triggered when component is about to added
        componentWillMount() {
            if (!this.props.userAuthenticated) {
                console.log("navigate to login");
                this.context.router.push('/login');
            }
        }
        // before component updated
        componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
            if (!nextProps.userAuthenticated) {
                console.log("navigate to login");
                this.context.router.push('/login');
            }
        }
        render() {
            return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
        }
    }
    AuthFilter.contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return { userAuthenticated: state.authenticated };
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthFilter);
}
```

And then add wrapping to your route component as:

```
Route path="/asset" component={AuthFilter(AssetRoute)}/>
```